# QT on Windows: Invalid function argument when run from GDB

Tags: c++, qt

In a QT 5.4.2 project configured to use MinGW (from the 32-bit QT distribution) under Windows 7 x64, I'm seeing a problem where the program works fine normally, but crashes in GDB. I have traced the crash back to invalid argument being passed to my callback function from QML. It is a function defined on an object that is used as a context property. The function receives QString as its argument. When executing without gdb, its value is as expected. With gdb, it contains garbage (not random garbage, though, but the same particular garbage every time). Sample code:

```
class CallbackSink : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CallbackSink() {}

    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QString callTestString2(const QString &str) { return QString(""); }

    virtual ~CallbackSink() {}
};


class Sink : public CallbackSink {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Sink() {}

    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QString callTestString2(const QString &str) {
        const char *_str = str.toUtf8().constData();
        printf("_str=%s\n", _str);

        const char *_ret = "fdsa";
        QString ret = QString::fromUtf8(_ret);
        return ret;
    }

    virtual ~Sink() {}
};
```

QT initialization code:

gui.h:

```
struct Gui {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<QApplication> app;
    std::unique_ptr<QQmlApplicationEngine> engine;

    std::unique_ptr<CallbackSink> sink;

    QQuickWindow *window;

    Gui(std::unique_ptr<CallbackSink> s) : sink(std::move(s)) {}

    int run();

    virtual ~Gui() {}
};
```

gui.cpp:

```
int Gui::run() {
    char x[] = "BLAH BLAH";
    char *argv = x;
    int argc = 1;

    app = std::unique_ptr<QApplication>(new QApplication(argc,&argv));
    engine = std::unique_ptr<QQmlApplicationEngine>(new QQmlApplicationEngine());

    QQmlContext *objectContext = engine->rootContext();
    objectContext->setContextProperty("callbacks", &*sink);

    engine->load(QUrl("qrc:///myqml.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine->rootObjects().value(0);
    window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();

    int r = app->exec();

    return r;
}
```

And the relevant QML snippet:

```
Text {
    id: mytext
    wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: '<p>call 2: `' + callbacks.callTestString2('foo') + '`'
}
```

I guess it's worth noting that I'm compiling all my GUI code as a DLL, and the executable links against it from a separate project.

When running from gdb, I see this printed (same thing irrespectively of the argument value):

```
_str=ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■ю■☺!=4/Ц♠↑☺
```

**UPDATE**: also tried with Qt 5.5, same problem.

**UPDATE 2**: I have created a new QtQuick Application project from template in QtCreator and made minimal changes to it in order to reproduce the issue. It happens in this project, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char *_str = str.toUtf8().constData();
printf("_str=%s\n", _str);
```

You have undefined behaviour here. `toUtf8()` returns a temporary object which will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. `constData()` returns a pointer which is not guaranteed to be valid after that temporary object is destroyed. Try this instead:

```
printf("_str=%s\n", qPrintable(_str));
```